# Execute some code before Pytest runs

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using Pytest to test my code and I'm running into a little, but an infuriating issue.

One of the first things my program does is checking if there are any setting files available. If there aren't any it throws an error and calls `exit()`. This works well during normal runtime but messes with Pytest.

The solution I came up with is to simply create a temporary settings file for the duration of the tests, by copying the template settings file. I've already written and successfully tested the code to achieve that.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a Pytest hook that truly fires before everything else. This results in the program throwing the error before Pytest tries to create a temporary settings file. Which results in Pytest failing before it can perform any tests.

Does anyone know of a way to fire a function before Pytest does or loads anything? Preferably within Pytest itself.

### Some code context:

#### Throwing the error and exit

This snippet runs on the import of the `settings` module.

```
if len(cycles) == 0:
    log.error("No setting files found. Please create a file " +
              "in the `settings` folder using the Template.py.")
    exit()
```

#### Creating the temporary settings file

This code should be the very first thing Pytest runs.

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """ Create a test settings file """
    folderPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    folderPath = os.path.split(folderPath)[0] + "/settings"

    srcfile = folderPath + '/Template.py'
    dstfile = folderPath + '/test.py'

    shutil.copy(srcfile, dstfile)
```

#### Removing the temporary settings file

This code should be one of the last things Pytest runs.

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """ Delete the test settings file """
    folderPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    folderPath = os.path.split(folderPath)[0] + "/settings"

    os.remove(folderPath + "/test.py")
```

#### Pytest output

With the call to `exit()` disabled, so you can see the execution order.

```
Lakitna$ pytest -v -s
 No setting files found. Please create a file in the `settings` folder using the Template.py. 
TEMPORARY SETTINGS FILE CREATED
========================= test session starts ==========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/lakitna/Documents/Github/Onaeri-tradfri/Onaeri, inifile:
collected 24 items
```

Comment: Have you looked into this https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html

Comment: @progmatico sadly these hooks don't work like I need them to. In my case, they have the same problem as `pytest_sessionstart` and `pytest_sessionfinish` as shown above

Comment: May be this is not pytest issue but python itself. Python run code from all your `import` if this code is not inside sobroutines. So just remove that initialization code and call it explicitely.

Comment: How about using `conftest.py` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53690092/248616

Answer (score 28):

Add `conftest.py` to your project with below code and add your code to method `pytest_configure`

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    pass # your code goes here

# other config
```

Comment: Works for me, this is the exact solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad that it helps

Comment: This solution is clearly better than the author's answer. This is simpler, and uses the existing `conftest.py` and fewer lines of code. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Super happy to hear your compliment! Thank you thank you!

Comment: Issue I'm seeing with this is that it will load all plugins THEN load the `conftest.py`/`pytest_configure`

Answer (score 3):

First, pytest tries to make all imports as relative as possible: this means that if you keep your tests in `package/tests`, then even your conftest will be imported as `package.test.conftest`. To do that import, `package.__init__` will be called (unfortunately for you).

In order to run run some configuration before, the tests need to be moved out of the package tree. I ran into [just such a problem](https://github.com/Becksteinlab/GromacsWrapper/pull/165) recently.

As shown in a [pytest issue thread](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3261#issuecomment-369740536), `pytest_configure` is actually called before `pytest_sessionstart`, but both occur before test collection, so either should be fine.

```py
# contents of tests/conftest
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import pytest  # if necessary
# cannot import package here (and likely not in `tests.__init__` either)


folderPath = Path.cwd()
folderPath = folderpath / 'package' / 'settings'
srcfile = folderPath / 'Template.py'
dstfile = folderPath / 'test.py'


def pytest_configure(config):
  """ Create a test settings file """
  # can use `config` to use command line options
  shutil.copy(srcfile, dstfile)


def pytest_unconfigure(config):
  """ Delete the test settings file """
  os.remove(dstfile)
```

This should work if you have your folders structured like this:

```
root_folder
├── package
│   ├── settings
│   │   └── Template.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module1.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py      # Does not import package
    ├── conftest.py      # Does not import package
    └── test_module1.py  # Can import package
```

pytest can then be invoked in the normal way: `pytest -flags` (or `pytest tests -flags`) when working from `root_folder`.

If you want to set up your settings file in different ways depending on [custom command line flags to pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html), you can do that as well in `conftest.py`. They can then be accessed in `pytest_configure` as `config.getoption(...)`.

---

Note: this syntax assumes Python 3.6+ with the use of `Path`s as arguments to `os.remove` and `shutil.copy`.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution.

After some additional research, I found out that Pytest preloads all modules. This means that you can never run code before a module import unless you can find a hook before the collection phase. There is no such hook as far as I know. I really wanted to make this work within Pytest, but it seems to be impossible.

Instead, I created a `__main__.py` file in my test folder with the following content:

```
import pytest
import os
import shutil

"""
Create a setting file for the test procedure
"""
folderPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
folderPath = os.path.split(folderPath)[0] + "/settings"

srcfile = folderPath + '/Template.py'
dstfile = folderPath + '/test.py'

shutil.copy(srcfile, dstfile)

"""
Actually run pytest
"""
pytest.main()

"""
Remove the test settings file
"""
os.remove(dstfile)
```

This code creates a temporary settings file, starts Pytest, and then removes the temporary file again.

I can now run the test procedure as follows:

```
$ python3 test
```

Pytest flags still work as normal. For example, if you want more verbose output you can do the following:

```
$ python3 test -v
```

Comment: For anyone else who is looking to run code before pytest runs, the import things here are that _A)_ You create a Python file to run your tests from, and _B)_ That file includes the line `pytest.main()`. Anything before this line will be run before pytest runs.

Answer (score 0):

This deviates from what you are looking for, but I would question your strategy. I suspect your code is not test friendly. The available hooks should suffice for setting up test pre-conditions like that. That is if your tests need some file, somehow setup that file first in setup, delete them with teardown, or use fixtures as per the pytest docs.

If you don't actually need the file for the tests to run, except that the code tests its existence, you can fake its existence with mocks.

But you have code running on module import that is testing (without actually being test code) a pre-condition and with user interaction.
And I think you shouldn't do this.

Remove the execution of that code running with import (make it a function or class). And invoke it in some other initialising place of your code.

Setup the file (with pytest hooks). Test code that uses the settings file.
Teardown the file (with pytest hooks).

You can in alternative completely fake the file by overriding the data read with fake data, using some data struture and functions to read/write,
simulating the file.

Test the code that tests for the settings file existence (use mocks).

Test your other code methods.

Do not mix things. Try to write methods that do one thing. Test one thing at a time. Test your business code. User interaction is another thing. If you also want to test UI, don't do it at the same time (I mean in the same code).

Answer (score -3):

To run some code before and after the actual code of your test, you can use pytest fixtures:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def context():
    """What to do before/after the test."""
    print("Entering !")
    yield
    print("Exiting !")


def test_stuff(context):
    """The actual code of your test"""
    print("Running the test")
```

This displays:

```
Entering !
Running the test
Exiting !
```

To use the fixture, just pass a parameter with the same name as input of the test function. The yield instruction acts like a separator between what's done before and after the test.

Comment: This would work great if the error was thrown in a function. But in my case, it's thrown on module import. And since Pytest seems to preload modules this sadly won't work in this particular case.